# SwitchYard error while deploying JBoss Fuse on EAP container

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, switchyard

I have downloaded jboss-eap-7.0.0.Beta.zip and extracted it and I am able to execute the server in both the standalone and domain modes. However, when I try to deploy the Fuse jar fuse-eap-installer-6.2.1.redhat-084.jar on it, I am getting following error.

The error shown on console while executing the jar is:

```
java -jar ../fuse-eap-installer-6.2.1.redhat-084.jar
Skip already existing patch file: fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-1.6.2.zip
Skip already existing patch file: fuse-eap-distro-6.2.1.redhat-084.zip
Run command: java -Djboss.home=.      -Dlogging.configuration=file:bin/fusepatch-logging.properties -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.patch --add file:fusepatch/repository/fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-1.6.2.zip
Repository already contains fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-1.6.2
Run command: java -Djboss.home=. -Dlogging.configuration=file:bin/fusepatch-logging.properties -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.patch --add file:fusepatch/repository/fuse-eap-distro-6.2.1.redhat-084.zip
Repository already contains fuse-eap-distro-6.2.1.redhat-084
Run command: java -Djboss.home=. -Dlogging.configuration=file:bin/fusepatch-logging.properties -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.patch --update fuse-patch-distro-wildfly
Patch fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-1.6.2 has already been applied
Run command: java -Djboss.home=. -Dlogging.configuration=file:bin/fusepatch-logging.properties -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.patch --update fuse-eap-distro
Patch fuse-eap-distro-6.2.1.redhat-084 has already been applied
Run command: java -Djboss.home=. -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.config --configs camel,switchyard --enable
 Processing config for: camel
    Writing 'layers=fuse' to: ./modules/layers.conf
    Enable camel configuration in: ./standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
Error: Did not find the <extensions> element
Error: Command did not terminate normally
```

The EAP server log shows the following exception:

```
12:09:19,798 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.switchyard-bpel-console.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.switchyard-bpel-console.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.switchyard-bpel-console.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.switchyard.component.bpel:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1042)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1398)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1426)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:238)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 5 more
```

Please let me know if there are any suggestions on getting this work.

Meanwhile, I checked that the standalone directory for camel configuration, but I don't find any. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

According  [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Installation_on_JBoss_EAP/Installation_Guide_Overview.html)  you can't use JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 with JBoss EAP 7. If you want to use JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 you have to install it on top of JBoss EAP 6.4.x.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this post for answer for this question, I was able to fix this issue by installing Jboss fuse 6.2.1 over Jboss EAP 6.4 as Jboss recommendation.

[How to do BPEL,BPM deployment in JBoss AS7/EAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937678/how-to-do-bpel-bpm-deployment-in-jboss-as7-eap)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline