# How to do BPEL,BPM deployment in JBoss AS7/EAP

Tags: jboss, jbpm, jbossfuse, switchyard

Jboss says to deploy BPEL applications in Either EAP or AS7 servers. I could nt deploy BPEL applications in Any of those servers. When searched in google, Some posts says Switchyard is better to use for BPEL or BPM applications and its been aquired by JBoss and release by JBoss as JBossFuse. I tried JBossFuse as well, JBossFuse cannot detect BPEL or BPM applications either through Eclipse. I have tried WSO2 and it was better than JBoss servers. I would like to use JBoss stack of products as it is a big community. Can someone suggest which is best server to deploy BPEL or BPM applications in Jboss servers.
Please provide links to download as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a  trick with Jboss EAP 6.4 server not recognizing BPEL / BPM (Switchyard). When you install vanilla EAP 6.4 server , you wont have Fuse packages installed in it. They say you can work with fuse server, But fuse server wont be working as EAP server works from Eclipse(JBDS). So you need to install Fuse over your EAP server to recognize your BPEL/BPM or Swithyard applications.Check out below solution from Redhat website.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Installation_on_JBoss_EAP/Installing_Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse_on_EAP.html

Answer (score 0):

Now that RiftSaw (http://riftsaw.jboss.org/), which is the integration layer for Apache ODE with JBoss EAP/WildFly, is part of SwitchYard, SwitchYard is the only framework under JBoss umbrella that enables you to deploy/run BPEL applications.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SWITCHYARD/BPEL

However, one thing you should note is that in SwitchYard BPEL applications can be developed only in the form of a SwitchYard service, so you also need to learn SwitchYard, which is a kind of ESB or integration framework on top of SCA & CDI/Camel. I wouldn't recommend BPEL compared to BPM for a new project, because the JBoss community for BPEL is not active. In contrast to Apache ODE, SwitchYard is not designed to run a plain BPEL application.

On the other hand, if you want to develop/deploy BPM applications on JBoss EAP/WildFly, then jBPM (http://www.jbpm.org/) is the option. As jBPM is the premier open-source BPM project and is being actively developed, it would be the best choice if you start a business process project.

As a bonus, if you want to use JBoss Fuse, there is an official integration pack for jBPM:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Integration_Guide/index.html

Also note that JBoss Fuse includes SwitchYard, so you can develop/run BPEL SwitchYard services on both Karaf and EAP containers.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply, So If i want to just run BPEL(Not talking anything about BPM/jBPM), I need to learn SwitchYard and do the BPEL integration there and deploy it in RiftSaw / Jboss Fuse? If yes, Could you provide me exact download link of JbossFuse server that will allow me deploy switchyard project. I am trying to deploy HelloWorld Switchyard project thru JBDS, which is not recognizing SwitchYard project to deploy in it. Please help

Comment: Yes. And here you can find JBoss Fuse (for dev use only unless you have a subscription): http://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/
If you prefer an open-source community option, you can directly use SwitchYard on EAP/WildFly. See: http://switchyard.jboss.org/downloads
If you'd like to use SwitchYard in JBDS, don't forget to install the Integration Stack plugin as well: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/7.1/html/Integration_Stack_Guide/index.html